# find data in json data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to fetch some data from json file in Javascript

I have json data like this :

```
var bib = {
"AnthesGarcia-HernandezEtAl2016": {
    "author": "C. Anthes and R. J. Garcia-Hernandez and M. Wiedemann and D. Kranzlmuller",
    "booktitle": "2016 IEEE Aerospace Conference",
    "doi": "10.1109/AERO.2016.7500674",
    "file": "AnthesGarcia-HernandezEtAl2016.pdf:AnthesGarcia-HernandezEtAl2016.pdf:PDF",
    "keywords": "virtual reality, survey, aerospace",
},
"Bastos2014": {
    "author": "Bastos, Ricardo S",
    "file": "Bastos2014.pdf:Bastos2014.pdf:PDF",
    "institution": "DTIC Document",
    "keywords": "maritime, military, submarine, training, simulator, virtual reality, web, webgl, navy"

},
"Baum1994": {
    "author": "Baum, David R",
    "keywords": "patent, virtual reality, gestures, aviation, training, head-mounted-display, HMD, gloves",

}
```

how can I fetch data like this in js:

```
    var keywords = {
    "keywords-name": { // keywords-name as example : virtual reality
        "repeat": "??"

    },
    "keywords-name2": {
       "repeat": "??"
       },
    "keywords-name3": {
       "repeat": "??"
}, ...
```

I don't know how to do this in javascript..

Comment: It's unclear what you're wanting. What would you like the output to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys),
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control),
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control) and
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split),

you can do it like this:

```js
var bib = {
  "AnthesGarcia-HernandezEtAl2016": {
    "author": "C. Anthes and R. J. Garcia-Hernandez and M. Wiedemann and D. Kranzlmuller",
    "booktitle": "2016 IEEE Aerospace Conference",
    "doi": "10.1109/AERO.2016.7500674",
    "file": "AnthesGarcia-HernandezEtAl2016.pdf:AnthesGarcia-HernandezEtAl2016.pdf:PDF",
    "keywords": "virtual reality, survey, aerospace",
  },
  "Bastos2014": {
    "author": "Bastos, Ricardo S",
    "file": "Bastos2014.pdf:Bastos2014.pdf:PDF",
    "institution": "DTIC Document",
    "keywords": "maritime, military, submarine, training, simulator, virtual reality, web, webgl, navy"
  },
  "Baum1994": {
    "author": "Baum, David R",
    "keywords": "patent, virtual reality, gestures, aviation, training, head-mounted-display, HMD, gloves"
  }
};

var keywords = Object.keys(bib).reduce((a, v) => {
  bib[v].keywords.split(/\s*,\s*/).forEach(kw => {
    a[kw] = a[kw] || {repeat: 0};
    a[kw].repeat++;
  });

  return a;
}, {});

console.log(keywords)
```

Comment: tnx so much. but how can I customize your code, that to see output like that :
nodes: [{id: "virtual reality" ,repeate : 3}, {id: "survey" , repeat: 1}

Comment: I wrote this code but don't work correctly :

    var res = {
     nodes: []
    };
    for (var key in repeats) {
      if (repeats.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var temp = repeats[key];
        temp["id"] = key;
        res.nodes.push(temp);
      }
    }

Answer (score -1):

u can try this:

```
alert(keywords.keywords-name)
```

should get the value.

Comment: Not only does it not answer the question, it won't even execute.

Comment: i am sorry, i misunderstand the question after seeing @RobbyCornelissen answer. Thx for pointing out my mistake.